# Android sqlite index on android 2.3

Tags: android, sqlite, indexing, android-2.2-froyo, android-2.3-gingerbread

I have two device: HTC Desire with Android 2.2 Froyo and HTC Evo 3D with Android 2.3 Gingerbread.

My sql request:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Album.titre, Serie.nbAlbum 
  FROM Serie, Album 
  WHERE Serie.titre=Album.serieTitre AND Album.shz=1
```

with a non-indexed database :

```
htc evo 3d : Everything works fine, the query runs in ~1 second.
htc desire : This is much longer! about 30 - 50 seconds.
```

So, i tried to index my table with :

```
CREATE INDEX IDX_ALBUM_SHZ on ALBUM (shz)
CREATE INDEX IDX_ALBUM_SERIETITRE on ALBUM(serieTitre)
```

but the result were reversed!

```
HTC Desire : Really fast, ~1 second.
HTC Evo 3d : Very slow, more than 20 seconds
```

Have you an idea of ​​what's happening?
It is there was a significant change in how to manage sqlite between froyo and gingerbread?

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If no solution, I solved my problem with a simple check of version at the database creation / import, and add / remove indexes accordingly.

However, I remain open to a smarter!

Answer (score 0):

That is most probably related to the file systems which those phones are using. As far as I know most Samsung phones use RFS file system, which licks the dust in terms of disk access time performance. And HTC phones mostly use ext3(as far as I know). I can not think of any other difference in your case.

Comment: Is it possible that the filesystem affects the sqlite index? this seems strange. Moreover, I could test on a sony S tab, galaxy tab 10.1 and ASUS transformers any in 3.2 everything works perfectly, with and without indexes.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this happens dut the difference in versions of Android. From 2.2 to 2.3 there were a lot of changes in perfomance stuff.
I have 2 devices for developing: one runs on 2.2.2 and the other runs 2.3.3. The perfomance differs a lot.
The most likely cause is that 2.3 runs on ext4 file system (froyo runs on YAFFS) and it is just faster)

Comment: Even so, with indexes, froyo is much faster than gingerbread in my case